# como seleccionar los elementos que contengan una fecha dentro de un rango de fechas de entrada y salida que están en dos columnas

Tags: php, mysql

Tengo una tabla llamada reservas donde aparecen 2 columnas entrada y salida. Luego tengo una el mes y el año en dos variables y necesito saber si ese mes de ese año está contenida dentro de esas dos.
La idea es mirar la disponibilidad de una fecha comprobando las reservas existentes.

Tengo el mes y el año:

```
$month = 12;
$year=2020;

Tabla 
id, nombre ..etc entrada, salida
```

Esta consulta funciona pero es de una fecha especifica con un día, yo necesito saber las fechas ocupadas de todo el mes para que se muestre en un calendario.
Debería hacer una consulta por mes y año que me devuelva todas las filas que contengan ese mes de ese año.

```
SELECT * FROM reservas WHERE '2020-12-16' BETWEEN entrada AND salida;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
select * from reservas
where YEAR(fecha) between
YEAR(entrada) and YEAR(salida) and
MONTH(fecha) between
MONTH(entrada) and MONTH(salida);
```

Las **funciones YEAR y MONTH** extraen el año y el mes de una fecha, por tanto aquí se usan esas funciones para obtener las reservas del intervalo deseado.

Comment: Esta consulta funciona perfectamente, es exactamente lo que buscaba. Muchas gracias.

Answer (score 0):

Viendo que solo pasas datos del Año y el Mes y que el día no se tiene en cuenta, podrías comprobar que dicha fecha es mayor o igual a entrada y menor o igual a salida.

```
//Haces una variable para usar como fecha, que este compuesta por el año y el mes
$fecha = $year.'-'.$month.'-01 00:00:00'; //El 00:00:00 lo puedes quitar si en base de datos lo que guardas es un date y no un datetime

//En el caso de que también quisieras comprobar por día, simplemente el día tendría que ser una variable más
$fecha = $year.'-'.$month.'-'.$day.' 00:00:00';
```

```
//La consulta
SELECT * FROM reservas WHERE entrada >= fecha AND salida <= fecha;
```